# Python "Guess your Number" Error

Tags: python, numbers

I am making a guess your number game (the computer guess a number the human thinks of using higher/lower input) on python with help from a book.  I started learning python yesterday and have spent all day today looking for help but just get confused.  Here is the code (so far) and the error.

```
import random
print("Welcome to the Pick a Number Game!  Pick a number between 1 and 10 and I \n will guess it!")
number = random.randint (1, 10)
print("Are you thinking of", number,"?")
guess = input("Am I right on, higher, or lower? ")
if guess == "higher":
    number2 = random.randint (number, 10)
    input("Are you thinking of", number2,"?")    
elif guess == "lower":
    number3 = random.randint (1, number)
    input("Are you thinking of", number3,"?")                              
elif guess == "right on":
    print("I won!  Thanks for playing!")
    input("Press the enter key to exit.")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Number Challenge.py", line 8, in <module>
    input("Are you thinking of", number2,"?")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

I am lost and I do not understand similar questions' answers.   I would appreciate the solution to the code and an explanation you can give.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code thinks you are adding three arguments into the input function (because of the commas), when it only takes one. Use concatenation:

```
input("Are you thinking of " + str(number2) + " ?")
```

We call `str()` here to convert the integer to a string. We can't do concatenation with an integer and a string; they have to be the same type.

You can also use `.format()`:

```
input("Are you thinking of {} ?".format(number2))
```

Comment: when I add in your change it gives me this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Number Challenge.py", line 8, in <module>
    input("Are you thinking of" + number2 + "?")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Wow!  Thanks you so much!  If there is anyway I can upvote you profile or anything please let me help!  Thanks for following up!